# how can i eliminate date modified grouping from my documents?

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, when I display "my documents", the folders are grouped by date modified.  How can I display all folders in alpha order without regard to date modified?

Comment: Clicking just the "Name" header should do it. Or do you mean make this the default view for all local folders

Comment: Howard, click on and go into the folder in question and once in it press these keys in this order one after the other Alt, V, G, Down [arrow] 8 times, and then Enter—This should remove the grouping. Then press these keys one after the other Alt, V, O, and Enter—This will sort the folder by Name. The press Alt, V, Y, O and go over to the View tab, and select "Apply to Folders" option within the top Folder Views section and this should make that stick for all folders you open with File Explorer moving forward. Let me know if it helps, & I'll be happy to make an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 8):

On the View tab in any Explorer Window, there is a "Group By" dropdown menu. Just untick "Date Modified" to remove grouping by Date.

Or

Right Click in a blank area of the Explorer Window, Select `Group By` and then select `(none)`.

Comment: Thanks. Solution is working. On Windows 11 grouping is very well hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In the explorer window where your folders are listed (objects in right pane, not the navigation pane on the left), right click the empty space (make sure no sub folders are selected/highlighted), then, from the context menu, select the "Sort by" sub menu, then click "Name" instead of "Date modified".  Note that if you're using a touch screen, a long press (5 seconds) will bring up the context menu like right clicking a mouse / trackball does.